# Facebook Graph API unknown method

Tags: ios, facebook

Hello
I want to represent this one:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type= … CESS_TOKEN

with this:

```
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"checkin", @"type", token,@"access_token",
                                    nil];
    [facebook requestWithMethodName:@"search?"
                           andParams:params
                       andHttpMethod:@"GET"
                         andDelegate:self];
```

I am getting unknown method error? What is wrong here?

Comment: "https://graph.facebook.com/search?type= … CESS_TOKEN" what???

Comment: type=checkin&accesstoken=.... but nevermind I found it

Answer (score 0):

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"search" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```